# How do I download an attachment in the Description section of a Jira issue?

Tags: jira

When I click on the attachment icon, I instead activate the editor.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Right-clicking doesn't give an option to download the attachment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First select some random text in the issue description and then click on the attachment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that didn't work for me.  It just activated the editor, same as with a normal click.

Comment: You have to first select some random text in your issue description and then shift-click on your attachment. I hope they will fix this soon. So far, I can't find any related issue on Atlassian Support..

Comment: Ok if I first select some text of the Description, then when I click on the PDF attachment it opens it in the same tab.  I don't need to shift-click.  If you update your answer, I'll accept/upvote it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Nevermind I just rewrote it myself.

Comment: You're right. Thanks.